# Output Pins not showing in Sensors

Tags: gpio

The [ScratchGPIO package from Simplesi.net](http://simplesi.net/scratchgpio7-launched/) is a great addition to the Basic Scratch for Raspberry Pi Model 2 B++.  When I downloaded the 5-15-2015 latest Raspbian image and V7 of Scratch GPIO, my options for sensors initially included all the output pins.  Then suddenly, the only options are:

```
slider
light
sound
resistance-A (through resistance-D)
tilt
distance.
```

and previous projects with pins don't work.  Do I need to do anything to restore the output pins as sensors?

Comment: Sounds like you are playing with [SimpleSi's (CympleCy's) ScratchGPIO package](http://simplesi.net/scratchgpio7-launched/). I think you get a better response (Simon is pretty good in responding to comments on his website) if you post your problem at the link above (http://simplesi.net/scratchgpio7-launched/). It is best to include any output you get when you start ScratchGPIO, plus the commands you use to start the package, in your post on that site.

Answer (score 0):

Try these [instructions about scratchgpio](http://simplesi.net/how-to-debug-scratchgpio/) out.

Comment: In keeping with [our policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.

Comment: Considering the OP never contacted me - I'd delete whole post :)